# Using proc mixed to estimate parameters

Tags: sas, mixed-models

I have a mixed model with the following parameters:

- A slope and intercept term for group 1
- A different slope and intercept term for group 2
- A random effect which is indexed by group/subject within group

Is there a way to model this using proc mixed? I can't seem to figure out how to get different slopes/intercepts for the two groups.

Answer (score 1):

This shows a simple model with separate intercept and slope.  First BY GROUP then with GROUPS as a factor, and pooled estimate of error.  Maybe if you should some example data we can figure the RANDOM part.

```
data group;
   do group=1,2;
      do x = 1 to 10;
         y = rannor(1);
         output;
         end;
      end;
   Run;
ods select SolutionF;
proc mixed;
   by group;
   model y = x / solution;
   run;
ods select SolutionF;
proc mixed;
   class group;
   model y = group x(group) / noint solution;
   run;
```

[image]